# Create a StorageFile from path Win8.1

Tags: c#, file, windows-8.1

I want to manually create a `StorageFile` from a path, but there is no constructor for a `StorageFile`.

Is there a simple way to do a thing like this?

```
StorageFile f = new StorageFile("C:\song.mp3");
```

Comment: You want to store a file inside Isolated Storage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(item.Path);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync.aspx

Comment: What about non-existent file that I'm about to createt?

Comment: It is non-existent but you must know where it is going to be i.e. its path.  Right?

Comment: @Kugel, you need to create empty dummy file in advance, for example `using (System.IO.File.Create(filename)) { ; }`.